# Creating pointer array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

So I'm trying to create an array of pointers to an object for a templated list. I've looked at a bunch of other similar questions but I still can't get mine to work, I'm guessing something is wrong with the syntax.

Here is the class definition for my GLRow:

```
//************************************************************************************
// GLROW CLASS
//************************************************************************************

template <class DT>
class GLRow; //class prototype

template <class DT>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& s, GLRow<DT>& oneGLRow);

template <class DT>
class GLRow {

        friend ostream& operator<< <DT>(ostream& s, GLRow<DT>& oneGLRow);

        protected:
                DT* _Info;
                int _Next;
                int _Down;

        public:
                GLRow ();
                GLRow (const DT& newInfo);
                GLRow (const GLRow<DT>& anotherOne);
                GLRow<DT>& operator= (const GLRow<DT>& anotherOne);             //Make sure you do a$
                int getNext();
                int getDown();
                DT& getInfo() const;
                int setNext(int n);
                int setDown(int d);
                int setInfo (const DT& x);
                ~GLRow(); //destructor
};
```

Here is the class definition for my ArrayGLL:

```
//************************************************************************************
// ARRAYGLL CLASS
//************************************************************************************

template <class DT>
class ArrayGLL; //class prototype

template <class DT>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& s, ArrayGLL<DT>& oneGLL);

template <class DT>
class ArrayGLL {

        friend ostream& operator<< <DT>(ostream& s, ArrayGLL<DT>& OneGLL);


                protected:
                GLRow<DT>* myGLL;
                int maxSize;                                            //Maximum size of the array $
                int firstElement;
                int firstFree;

        public:
                ArrayGLL ();
                ArrayGLL (int size);
                ArrayGLL (ArrayGLL<DT>& anotherOne);
                ArrayGLL<DT>& operator= (ArrayGLL<DT>& anotherOne);
                void display ();                                        //display in parenthesis for$
                int find (DT& key);                                     //return the index position $
                void findDisplayPath (DT& Key);                         // as you travel through the$
                int noFree ();                                          //return the number of free $
                int size ();                                            //return the number of eleme$
                int parentPos(DT& Key);                                 // provide the location of t$
                GLRow<DT>& operator [] (int pos);                       //return the GLRow that is i$
                int getFirstFree();
                int getFirstElement();
                void setFirstFree (int pos);
                void setFirstElement (int pos);
                ~ArrayGLL ();                                           //destructor
};
```

Finally, this is my constructor for the ArrayGLL object:

```
template <class DT>
ArrayGLL<DT>::ArrayGLL()
{
maxSize = 10;
firstElement = 0;
firstFree = 0;

myGLL = new GLRow<DT>[10];
}
```

So as you can see I need an array of GLRow objects, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. When I call the constructor I get an invalid pointer error: "error in `main': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000014c3038 ***"

Comment: What does the constructor of `GLRow` do?

Comment: It just initializes the protected values

Comment: Does it initialize `_Info`? Your question mentions `array of pointer (to) objects c++`, but you're creating an array of objects here.

Comment: It does initialize _info, I think I misphrased my question, I am trying to create an array of objects

Comment: Right, the error you're getting is usually the result of trying to `free()` an invalid pointer, which you're not doing the the code above. Are you sure you're showing the code it's crashing on?